# Least line code to print a list of tuple in separate line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing, tuples

I have an input which is a list of tuples

```
s=[('c',2),('a',2),('b',3)]
```

I am expecting to have output as

```
c 2
a 2
b 3
```

I have used below three line code

```
s=[('c',2),('a',2),('b',3)]
for x in s:
  print(' '.join(map(str,x)))
```

Do we have any easier method rather than using for loop, map and join, it looks to me I have used too many function and I cant think of anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems much nicer to use *tuple unpacking* here:

```
s=[('c',2),('a',2),('b',3)]

for x, y in s:
    print(x, y)
```

Or this:

```
for x in s:
    print(*x)
```

Output:

```
c 2
a 2
b 3
```

Have a look at [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) from the documentation as to *why* the above works.